# Is there any way besides __init__ to receive values when constructing a class?

Tags: python, class, parameters, constructor, initialization

Here is an example:

```
# class.py
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str
    def __div__(self, sep):
        return self.str.split(sep)

>>> m = MyString('abcdabcdabcd')
>>> print m / 'b'
['a', 'cda', 'cda', 'cd']
```

The `__init__` method takes two parameters: the first one, `self`, is the instance object itself and `str`, the second, is a parameter passed in by the call. Is using `__init__` the only way to get values into the instance of my class?

Or, if I don't declare the method `__init__`, will expressions like `m = MyString('abcdabcdabcd')` cease to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default , when an object is created without parameter as follows

```
a = Class()
```

then the `__init__` method without parameter is called .

If you are not using `__init__` method , then the instances should be created without parameter as follows

```
class MyString:
    def __div__(self, sep):
        return self.str.split(sep)
m = MyString()
```

But if you want to add a parameter to your instance , you are bound to use **init** with parameter as in your program .

You can add class variable as follows

```
class MyString:
    str = ''
    def __init__(self,str):
        MyString.str = str
    def __div__(self, sep):
        return self.str.split(sep)
m = MyString('aSAA')
print(MyString.str)
#print(m.str)
['a', 'cda', 'cda', 'cd']
```

BUT a class variable is static and it is property of the class itself not particular to the object .

Answer (score 0):

The **initializer** (`Class.__init__()`) is *always* used to capture the arguments passed to the **constructor** (`Class()`). Without it, the constructor won't work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

@Ignacio got the **init** part. As for the question about it being the only way: no, you can get values into the instance of your class with any other function. In your example, you could have

```
def set_string(self, new_string):
    self.str = new_string()
```

or you could assign directly a value to your instance:

```
>>> m = MyString('abcdabcdabcd')
>>> m.str = "cbacbacba"
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the recommended practice is to use the `__init__` method as a "constructor" for new instances.  If you do not provide this method, then you can only create instances (the normal way) of the class by calling the class name without arguments.

Longer answer:

The most straightforward alternative to using `__init__` is to set attributes after the instance is created:

```
class Foo(object): pass
x = Foo()
x.bar = 3
```

A `staticmethod` in the class could be used to do something like this and return the instance, for example if you wanted to implement the singleton pattern.  A trivial example:

```
class Foo(object):
  @staticmethod
  def newinstance():  # no self here
    x = Foo()
    x.bar = 3
    return x

y = Foo.newinstance()
print y.bar  # prints 3
```

A more esoteric way to initialize an object without actually providing an `__init__` method is to [use a metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) to create instances differently than normal.  But metaclasses are seldom necessary in real-world applications.